# Number of blocks of linked elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab

How can one find the number of separated linked blocks using a symmetric matrix of 0s and 1s in Matlab?

For example in matrix A, if A(n,m)=1, member n and m are connected. Connected elements make blocks. In below matrix, members 2,3,4,5,6,8,9 are connected and make a block. Also, there are two clusters of size equal to 2 and one block of size 7.

```
A = [1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0          
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1]
```

Answer (score 0):

following your previous question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998101/link-matrix-in-matlab)) you can use labeling instead of binary indications and then sqrt the number of members in each block:

```
A = false(10);
% direct connections
A(2,3) = 1;
A(3,4) = 1;
A(5,6) = 1;
A(4,9) = 1;
A = A | A';
B = double(A | diag(ones(1,10))); % each node is connected to it self
B(B == 1) = 1:nnz(B); % set initial unique labels
while true
    B_old = B;
    % connect indirect connected nodes
    for node = 1:size(B,1)
        row = B(node,:);
        col = row';
        row = row > 0;
        col(col > 0) = max(col);
        cols = repmat(col,[1 nnz(row)]);
        % set the same label for each group of connected nodes
        B(:,row) = max(B(:,row) , cols);
    end
    if isequal(B,B_old)
        break
    end
end
% get block size
u = unique(B);
counts = hist(B(:),u);
% remove non connections
counts(u == 0) = [];
u(u == 0) = [];
% remove self connections
u(counts == 1) = [];
counts(counts == 1) = [];
% block size
blocksize = sqrt(counts);
```

Comment: please look at the code I added to the question. I tried to use your answer in my case, but it doesn't work

Comment: in the general case you obviously need to use `B = double(A | diag(ones(1,size(A,1)))); % each node is connected to it self`. but other than that, this particular A doesn't have two blocks (of size 2 and 7), but only one (of size 7). I mean, there's only one cluster -  2,3,4,5,6,8,9 - which only makes one block (of size 7, as the number of members in this connection/graph). or maybe I don't understand your meaning of "block".